# guest user access to custom community login page

Tags: visualforce, community

I created a custom visual force page to be our login page for our community. When I go to manage communities and try to set this as the login page it gives me

Error: you can only select pages that are accessible by the community guest user

I have read the getting started with communities and they don't accurately describe how to do accomplish this. I cannot see a community guest user to give access to this visual force page only profiles. I also cannot see a community guest user to add to a profile.

What do I have to do to allow this to work?

Comment: LMGTFU https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000B1ArIAK

Comment: @Rao Thanks that go me to the right part so i can now set the login page to my custom VF login page and it accepts the change. However it still shows the old one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a community inside Salesforce ,A salesforce site is automatically spun for you for accessing the community without login credentials as a guest user .

Lets take an example community set up to understand this

I have the communities as in screenshot

[image]

When i navigate to sites via set up menu,I see sites are already created by SFDC

[image]

The error is complaining your page is not accessible for your site .Below screen shot will help you on how you will add your VF to provide access to guest user

[image]

Comment: I cannot get to sites. When I go to the sites screen it wants me to register my force.com domain. This is in our sandbox as we want it all working fine before we roll it out. Our community works fine with the standard built in login page. When I try to register the existing domain that our community is using it complains that it already exists. So I cannot get the site detail page to give public access to the custom VF login page

Comment: Try using different domain names. Your community will also have same domain name once you register a domain

Comment: I found a way there by following the directions on Rao's link. Now it let me set it as my login page without complaining but it still shows the old login page when I bring it up. I went out and back into my community and it is showing my changes. So it should be using the custom VF login page but it's not

Comment: You will go to community management administration page and select login page as your page .

Comment: That was the part it wouldn't let me do until I gave the VF page public access which you showed me how to do. It is set in community management administrator as my VF page. It let me save it now without issue but it still shows me the built in standard login page when I go to the login URL for our community. However I can remove the /login from the URL and replace it with my custom VF Page name and that seems to work. Do I need to call my VF Page login?

Comment: You should also set login page config for sites .Go to sites and public access settings and say login required and select login page as your page .Hope that helps you

Answer (score 1):

**1. From Setup, click Customize > Communities > All Communities > Select the community**

[image]

**2. Under Workspaces > Pages, click the Go to Force.com link.**

[image]

**3. In the Site Visualforce Pages, click Edit.**

[image]

**4. Select your custom Visualforce page from the Available Visualforce Pages and Add it to Enabled Visualforce Pages.**

**5. Click Save**

Answer (score 0):

We also faced the same problem in our project . We noticed the User which is associated to the profile was inactivated . Once we activated the user it starts working .

[image]