# Visualforce page cannot be accessed from guest user?

Tags: visualforce, community, force.com-sites

I am trying to access a Visualforce page in a community from a guest user, and I cannot see it. I am trying just with a simple hello world page, to remove the ipothesis of object-related issues.
I assigned the visualforce page to the profile but still, it won't load at all, just a blank page. Any idea?

When i open the console i see only these 2 errors :

```
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for preview.salesforce-communities.com/auraFW/javascript/1643424164816/aura_prod.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE


DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for /ui-sfdc-javascript-impl/source/RecordGVP.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
```

This is what they should see : [image]

This is what they see : [image]

I added the visualfoce page in the profile that is listed here "test3 profile":
[image]

Comment: Just to confirm, you added the Visualforce page to the "public access" guest profile for the digital experience's site?

Comment: yes i added a screen shot now in the post

Comment: Is it happening in all of the browsers(even in incognito) ?

Comment: @Brian23Gt, 
You are facing the error because Chrome added support for source maps. Just try the steps mentioned below:
1.Go to the developer tools (F12 in the browser), then select the three dots in the upper right corner, and go to Settings.
2.Look for Sources, and disable the options mentioned below:
   "Enable JavaScript source maps"
   "Enable CSS source maps"
If you do that, that would get rid of the warnings.

Comment: @RaviTeja i did the steps you told me and this got rid of the warnings, but the visualforce page is still not loading.

Comment: @user43598 yes this happens in Safari too.

Comment: @Brian23Gt, Do you have any controller written for Vf page?

Comment: @RaviTeja no i was using before a visualforce page with a controller ( with class and page assigned to the user ). But now to reduce the possible errors i am just using an hello world page, without a controller.

<apex:page>
        <apex:slds />
    <b>Hello World!</b>
</apex:page>

Comment: @Brian23Gt, Can you refer this - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/110901/guest-user-access-to-custom-community-login-page? Check all the steps mentioned?

Comment: @RaviTeja Yes I already did all of this, the visualforce is added to the website settings.

Comment: ok i have an update, i tried the same thing with a website in my production org, instead of the sandbox and there it works. 
So i guess it has something to do with sandboxes.

Comment: now i can access the hello world visualforce page, but not one that prints fields text as output, even tho the guest user has access via setup to the object and fields.

Comment: Ok what i had to do is, i create a sharing rule with the guest user profile, because my object had private sharing. This was needed even tho i gave access to the fields and object to the user profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to fix this issue. If you are using some custom object, giving read permission to it and the fields was not enough for me because the object had private sharing model.
I had to create a sharing rule for this object and the guest user profile.
Then to be able to access the visualforce page, i just had to do the same things but in production. Somehow the sandbox didn't let me access the visualforce page as guest.

This finally solved the issue.